# append request param in double quotes

Tags: javascript, quotes, double-quotes

```js
var base = "/some/url?search=";
var value = '"VALUE IN QUOTES"';
$('#inner').append('<a href=' + '/some/url?search=' + value + '>link</a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inner"></div>
```

Hi.

My task is to add a double quoted parameters to request url. The resulting url should be

```
some/url?search="QUOTED VALUE WITH SPACES" "ANOTHER VALUE"
```

In other words it should be a single string with double quotes.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where is the quote used to wrap `href` value ?

Comment: `var base = '"/some/url?search="';` does not help

Comment: `'<a href=\'' + '/some/url?search=' + value + '\'>link</a>'` you did not wrap the href value, you did not even use `base`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. Encoding data to put in URLs
2. Generating a DOM including that.

To encode the data, use `encodeURIComponent`

```
var base = "/some/url?search=";
var value = '"VALUE IN QUOTES"';
var url = base + encodeURIComponent(value)
```

Then to build the DOM, use DOM methods (or jQuery wrappers around them). **Don't mash strings together**.

```
$('#inner').append(
    $("<a />").attr("href", url).text("link")
);
```